# iPhone Adjust Time in NSDate

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, substring, nsdateformatter

I use an RSS Parser that is listing times wrong.  Eastern Standard Time shows 1 hour later than what the actual time of the RSS Event is.  So, I am trying to figure out how I can adjust this in code, so that in the cellForIndexAtPathRow method of TableView, it will show correct time.  Here is the code I am using:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
```

The entry.articleDate comes from the RSS Parser earlier which returns:

```
NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"updated"];        
    NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339];
```

What do you think would be the best way to take the HH part of the string only, and subtract 1 off of it?

Comment: NSTimeInterval secondsforOneHour = 60 * 60;
NSDate *dateoneHourAhead = [articleDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsforOneHour];

Comment: Add `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"neededTimezone"]]` you should be good.

Comment: Eimantas answer worked best.  Since times were correct in Central I just set the Time Zone to America/Chicago and it shows the correct time no matter where the user is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply subtract an hour from the parsed date like so:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSDate *correctedDate = [entry.articleDate addTimeInterval:-3600*1];
NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:correctedDate];
```

However, I think the real problem lies in your RSS parser.  I'm betting that it's converting to your local time zone.  But, without seeing the actual `articleDateString` value I can't be sure.